# Any type mapping with different Id types

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, polymorphism, any

I'm working on an event-planning application for the contacts in a phone book. Avoiding all the `public virtual` and `protected` stuff, my `Contact` class looks like:

```
class Contact {
    //...
    Int32 Id { get; private set; } //primary key;
    String Name { get; private set; } 
    //...
}
```

A customer asked me to handle both his own phone book and my application's one. So I thought to extract an `IContact` interface from `Contact`, and to add another class `InternalContact` (this name sucks, I know), implementing the same interface. The problem is that the customer's db uses an assigned string as a primary key, so `Contact`''s Id type and `InternalContact`'s Id type will be different. Is it possible to map the `Invitation.Contact` property using an `<any>` type mapping, even is the Id types are different?

Thanks in advance,
Giulio

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but you could do something like this to create the classes:

```
interface IContact<T>
{
    T Id { get; }
}

public class Contact : IContact<int>
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class InternalContact : IContact<string>
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Generic? Uhm... sounds interesting. ;-) But is it possible? What should I write in the mapping file? Any link to any example about this technique? Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is possible. Here is a link to an introduction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It seems like you didn't get the 'core' of my question: I know what generics are, I don't know how to implement a polymorphic mapping with NHibernate where entities' Id are of different types. Or maybe I'm missing something?